# Cells and balls question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Question:**

> For this question we want to divide 13 identical balls to-6 different cells. How many options there are, in which all first three cells contain together **at least** 10 balls?

---

$Solution.$ we have two different approaches:

1. the first one is to divide first 10 balls to the first three cells and it has $\binom{10+3-1}{3-1}$ options, and then to take the balls that has remained (3 balls) and divide them with all the cells and for that $\binom{3+6-1}{6-1}$. So in total we get: $$\binom{12}{2}\binom{8}{5}$$
2. For the second approach, we can consider it to cases, in which in the first case we have 10 balls in first three cells, and then we divide all the remains to the 3 cells that are left. After that, we can take 11 balls to the first three cells and so on, till we get the following answer:
   $$\binom{12}{2}\binom{5}{2}+\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}+\binom{14}{2}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{15}{2}\binom{2}{2}$$

---

Now it can be easily checked that both approaches give different answers. It seems that in the first approach we have more options, and I don't understand how I consider there more options than the second approach consider.

Comment: the first method over counts, as there is no way to distinguish between the balls you initially place in the early cells and those you place there at the end.

Comment: @lulu so the first method is totally wrong? or can it improve to be a correct answer? when we are not over counts?

Comment: Sometimes it is possible to examine the multiple counting and cancel it out, but usually it isn't.  In this case, the patterns are pretty complicated.  Some cases are counted only once, some twice, and some more than twice.  Untangling that will come down to reproducing the second method.

Comment: @lulu Got it, thank you! :)